# Highlight New References in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies

I want to highlight the references that are newly included in my revised manuscript.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391698/how-to-highlight-references-numbers-and-citations-in-overleaf) is relevant. I used this solution to highlight the citation in the original text. But, it is not highlighting the references section. I can highlight some part of the citation part, like the title, with using \hl{} in the BibTeX reference. But, this solution is not highlighting all parts of reference.

```
@misc{griffiths2005introduction,
  title={\hl{Introduction to electrodynamics},
  author={Griffiths, David J},
  year={2005},
  publisher={AAPT}}
}
```

[image]